# Kendo UI Editor: Copy/Paste from Excel with format

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, editor, paste

Does anyone knows on how to retain the format of copied contents from Excel when pasting it in Kendo UI Editor? I want it to be as the same like what it is in excel, like its font-size, font-color and name?

I came across with this threads:

"http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/editor/copy-text-from-office-to-editor.aspx"
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/17028295/kendo-ui-editor-cut-copy-paste-with-msword

and it seems like there's an issue so I want to know if there are any configuration in kendo ui editor to avoid custom event handling.

Links that supports this functionality:

demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx
aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/editor/features/blackice_allFeatures/WebForm1.aspx
Also, the visualstudio.com (tfs azure)


Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first [link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/editor/copy-text-from-office-to-editor.aspx) describes the behavior of the Kendo UI editor:

> The content pasted from Word is cleaned automatically so that it becomes pure HTML. You can override this behavior by cleaning the content manually in the editor paste event -- update the html field of the event argument as needed, persisting any styles that you want to keep.

So if you want to use the Kendo UI Editor you should do as advised - clean the content inside the paste event.